# Electron Project: Crawlee Puppeteer can't find module "puppeteer" in compiled version

Tags: electron, web-crawler, puppeteer, crawlee

I recently added crawlee 3.0.2 to a project that has worked fine for months using a standard puppeteer setup (both with and without puppeteer-extra/stealth).

Everything runs fine when debugging and running through `npm start` in VS Code, but once compiled I hit an issue:

```
Unhandled Exception - Error: Cannot find module 'puppeteer'
```

I've traced the issue and the error appears to come from:

@crawlee\puppeteer\internals\puppeteer-launcher.js - line 18:

```
const { launcher = browser_1.BrowserLauncher.requireLauncherOrThrow('puppeteer', 'apify/actor-node-puppeteer-chrome'), ...browserLauncherOptions }
```

I'm not sure how to get crawlee to see the puppeteer module installed in the project.

I'm not sure if this is relevant/related, but at one point I was trying to use WebpackObfuscator and unpacked puppeteer from the compiled ASAR during builds, with a line in the main package.json:

```
"build": {
    "asar": true,
    "asarUnpack": [
      "**\\*.{node,dll}",
      "node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/**/*"
    ],
```

and

```
"extraResources": [
      "./assets/**",
      "node_modules/puppeteer"
    ],
```

I gave up on trying to use the obfuscator but found that passing the exectuablePath for puppeteer worked well, so I left it as-is (I can't remember now if the obfuscator was the only reason I did this in the first place - I think it was so that I could distribute with packaged chromium).

A couple of odd discrepancies I've noticed (I'm still fairly new to Electron/Node, so please forgive for the ignorance):

The package.json for crawlee has puppeteer listed for dependencies as:

```
"peerDependencies": {
        "playwright": "^1.21.1",
        "puppeteer": ">= 9.x <= 14.x"
    },
    "peerDependenciesMeta": {
        "playwright": {
            "optional": true
        },
        "puppeteer": {
            "optional": true
        }
   }
```

I was using a standalone puppeteer install well before adding crawlee in, and I believe it was newer than the 14.x, but it still ran fine at the version I had already added while building and testing.

I tried installing puppeteer v14 (downgrading), which updated the main project package.json to

```
"puppeteer": "^14.4.1",
```

But that didn't resolve the issue either. However, when running `npm view puppeteer version` it shows 16.1.0, regardless of what the package.json shows. So I can't make heads or tails of where the actual issue lies.

Any pointers on how to get crawlee to see the puppeteer package on compiled versions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for this by making sure to include dependencies as an external in webpack and to declare the node_modules path relative to your package.json in your package.json as an 'extraResource'.

Comment: Before writing an answer, please take the time to carefully read and understand the question. If you have any doubts or questions about the details of the problem, consider leaving a comment to ask for clarification. This will help ensure that the answers provided are accurate and useful.